# static member explicit definition

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, static-linking, static-initialization

Consider this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Wilma
{
    public:
        static int i;
        Wilma()
        {
            cout<<"\nWilma ctor\n";
            cout<<"\ni::"<<i<<"\n";
        }
};
class Fred
{
    public:
        Fred()
        {
            cout<<"\nFred ctor\n";

        }
        static Wilma wilma_;
};
int Wilma::i=44;//------------- LINE A
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    Wilma::i=a;//---------- LINE C
    Wilma w;
    Fred::wilma_=w;//---------- LINE B

}
```

here line A explicitly defines the static int a of Wilma class.(commented out to cause linker error)
and without which the linker gives undefined reference error.(because Wilma::i is actually being used,if i dont use it no linker errors are there.)

Same should be true for static Wilma wilma_ of Fred class,i.e it should be explicitly defined aswell..because it is also being used in the code at line B.
But thats not the case,no linker errors for Fred::wilma_ if its not been explicitly defined.
why?
Tested on gcc 4.5.2

**EDIT:**
I somehow got another doubt about this...

**LINE C** and **LINE B** both are trying to use static objects of a class,`int Wilma::i` and `Wilma Fred::wilma_` respectively.
But only a definition for `int Wilma::i` is mandatory?

Why isnt `Wilma Fred::wilma_;` mandatory?

I understand the answer that the **line B** is a no-op. but same can be said about **line C** too??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Wilma` has no non-static fields. `Fred::wilma_=w;` doesn't do anything.

**edit**

If there are no non-static members - there's no copy. Basically the assignment was a no-op and might just been optimized out by the compiler, and the linker never saw it. Adding a non-static member made the copy to be an actual operation that referenced the static variable, thus the compiler couldn't optimize it out and the linker saw it.

Comment: fine.. i added int j; to Wilma.. and linker error appears now.. but i didnt get the point and how Fred::wilma_=w; isnt doing anything??..thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @ashishsony - added explanation to the answer.

Comment: @ashishsony: Where is the error? Please edit your question accordingly. Are you trying to assign int j to something in the class? That is not allowed.

Comment: @littleadv.. just to extend the conversation,if this question is asked in an interview.. then what should one answer,because its difficult to guess how a compiler would optimize..especially in this case where optimizing or not-optimizing would end up in no-error or an error.

Comment: @ashishsony - I don't think the original code (with all-static Welma) would end in error regardless of optimization. If I were the interviewer, the answer I've given here would be more than satisfactory for me. Well, I gave it, after all:-)

Answer (score 1):

You declared `static int i;` in `Wilma`, but never defined it. So by adding back in *Line A*, it will cause Wilma::i to be **defined**, which is what the compiler is complaining about. So you have to **define** it somewhere outside the class and not inside main.

Finally, the Fred and Wilma classes are essentially empty (aside from a ctor and static class member). There is nothing to copy between them.

Edit: Based on the comments to @littleadv, you have to have an identical class if you are going to perform a copy. If you put an int j in the Wilma class but nothing in the Fred class, then it won't work because where should it put j in the Fred class?

Comment: my question isnt about static int i but static Wilma wilma_

Comment: @ashishsony: It's hard to read your question in the first place. Nevertheless, I answered it in the second paragraph.

Comment: oh my my! i think you have taken this question in some other sense..i added int j to Wilma,then i am copying a temp Wilma to static Wilma wilma_(of Fred).. no question of putting int j in Fred.